# Alsa: playing playing variable bitrate mp3file

Tags: alsa

While playing an mp3 file using ALSA , mp3 file is decoded using libmad which provides the sample rate and bit depth for each mp3 frame via callback `mad_header` .

While setting ALSA parameters using `snd_pcm_hw_params_set` would be done at the beginning , the sample rate and bit rate may change for next frames which need to be reset for proper playing

Questions:

- 1 should the sample rate and bit rate be set again for each frame (or optimally when they change)?
- 2 If the answer of Question #1 is Yes, would this interrupt playback? and how to handle it to avoid glitches and extra CPU load
- 3 if the answer of question #1 is NO, how will this affect playback quality and which bitrate/sample rate to maintain to achieve better playback experience ?